# Keep 2 words with special character in the same line? HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a h2 tag with the text Ab-Cd. But when the screen is resized horizontally, the Ab- and Cd comes in separate lines. I have already tried word-wrap css but not effect.
`<h2>..... Ab-Cd .....</h2>`

Is there any way to make Ab-Cd stick together in a responsive design?

Many Thanks!!

Comment: css. white-space: nowrap

Comment: Use `&#8209;` instead of the hyphen character (‑) in your HTML to define a  hyphen that does not break into a new line.

Comment: Additional tip: There are also non-breaking spaces if you ever have this problem :) Use `&nbsp`.  Strings separated with `&nbsp` will not be separated and put into separate lines.

Answer (score 1):

Use the non-breaking hyphens. Works just like the non-breaking spaces.